# Error:Exception in thread "main" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space

Tags: java, out-of-memory

My program is as follows:

```
import java.util.*;

class evenNumber {
    ArrayList<Integer> arrL=new ArrayList<Integer>();

    ArrayList<Integer> saveEvenNumber(int N) {
        if(N<2)
            System.out.println("N should be greater than 2");
        else 
            for(int i=1;i<N;i++)
            {
                while(i%2==0)
                {
                    arrL.add(i);
                }
            }

        return arrL;
    }

    void printEvenNumber() {
        Iterator<Integer> tr=arrL.iterator();
        while(tr.hasNext())
            {
                System.out.print(tr.next());
                System.out.print("*2, ");
            }
    }
}


public class First {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        evenNumber eN=new evenNumber();
        eN.saveEvenNumber(13);
        eN.printEvenNumber();
    }
}
```

I am getting the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
    at java.util.Arrays.copyOf(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.Arrays.copyOf(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.ArrayList.grow(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.ArrayList.ensureCapacityInternal(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.ArrayList.add(Unknown Source)
    at list.evenNumber.saveEvenNumber(First.java:15)
    at list.First.main(First.java:35)`
```

I have changed the size in *Run > Run configuration > Arguments* as mentioned in other posts on the same error but then also I am getting the same error.

What should I do?

Comment: You keep adding elements to your list in `while(i%2==0) {  arrL.add(i); }`. Independent of your memory settings, this **will** run out of memory sooner or later.

Comment: In addition to Andreas' comment I guess you want to use `if(i%2==0)` instead.

Comment: Your way of iterating in `printEvenNumber` is one way to do it, but a simple `for` loop would be more readable: `for (Integer i : arrL) { System.out.print(i); System.out.print("*2, "); }` would do the same.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When `i == 2`, the while loop will be executed forever and that's the reason why `java.lang.OutOfMemoryError` is thrown.

Add a `break;` after `arrL.add(i);`.

As Thomas commented, use **if statement** is more suitable here.

BTW, refer to [Naming Conventions](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-135099.html) for java naming. For your case, the first letter of class name should be capitalized. Use `EvenNumber` instead of `evenNumber`.

Comment: An if-statement would be the better solution here.